# Unable to create same scrypt digest between Ruby-s and Go-s implementations

Tags: ruby, go, libsodium, scrypt, nacl-cryptography

I'm having a problem of calculating the same scrypt digest between [RbNaCl](https://github.com/cryptosphere/rbnacl/) and [Go's implementation](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/scrypt/scrypt.go#L227).

Here's how I'm generating key with rbnacl:

```
opslimit = 2**20
memlimit = 2**24
digest_size = 32

digest = RbNaCl::PasswordHash.scrypt(
        password,
        salt,
        opslimit,
        memlimit,
        digest_size
)
```

*opslimit* and *memlimit* parameter values have been found from [documentation](https://github.com/cryptosphere/rbnacl/blob/d443d94fc7addc35d7ad519830b9380523551d88/lib/rbnacl/password_hash/scrypt.rb#L33-L34).

Here's my attempt to replicate same results with Go:

```
N := 32768
r := 8
p := 1
keyLength := 32

secretKeyBytes, _ := scrypt.Key(password, salt, N, r, p, keyLength)
```

Values for *N*, *r*, *p* and *keyLength* gotten from [documentation](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/scrypt#Key).

*password* and *salt* have same values.

I'm not a cryptographer, but as far as I understand there should be same cost factor values to get the same digest? The problem here is that since both implementations take different count of parameters it's hard for me to find the correct combination too. Any ideas how to make cost factors match between these two implementations so that I could calculate same scrypt hashes between two programming languages?

Answer (score 5):

Managed to calculate *N*, *p* and *r* from *opslimit* and *memlimit* by looking into libsodium's function [pickparams](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium/blob/master/src/libsodium/crypto_pwhash/scryptsalsa208sha256/pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256.c#L19), which was called by *crypto_pwhash_scryptsalsa208sha256*, which in turn was called by Ruby's scrypt implementation at RbNaCl.

Here's the relevant code to convert *opslimit* and *memlimit* to appropriate *N*, *p* and *r* to be used by other scrypt implementations, which offer lower level API for scrypt if anyone else needs it in the future:
https://gist.github.com/jarmo/22f871076ff70e39b54e69c6305c020f

Just change *opslimit* and *memlimit* variable values in *main* and compile it with gcc and run it to get values for *N*, *r* and *p*.

All in all the problem was that Go exposes lower level API than RbNaCl even though they are doing the same thing.